# Repetitive use of a function: how to perform this - with an array

Tags: php, function, dom, document

First of all-many season-greetings and a happy new year to all of you! Have a great time!!

The following code is a solution that returns the labels and values in a 
formatted array ready for input to mysql. Very nice;-)

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://schulen.bildung-rp.de/gehezu/startseite/einzelanzeige.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5buid%5d=60119');
$divElement = $dom->getElementById('wfqbeResults');

$innerHTML= '';
$children = $divElement->childNodes;
foreach ($children as $child) {
$innerHTML = $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($innerHTML);
//$divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagname('td');

    /*** the array to return ***/
    $out = array();
    foreach ($divElementNew as $item)
    {
        /*** add node value to the out array ***/
        $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';

} 

?>
```

That bit of code works very fine and it performs an operation that i intend to call upon multiple times. Therefore it makes sense to wrap it in a function. We can name it whatever we want- Let us just name it "multiload". I tried to do this with the following code - but this does not run... I am still not sure where to put the uid - inside or outside the function...

```
    <?php

    function multiload ($uid) {
    /*...*/
    //  $uid = '60119';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

             $dom->loadHTMLFile('basic-url ' . $uid);


         }

    multiload ('60089');
    multiload ('60152');
    multiload ('60242');
    /*...*/

    $divElement = $dom->getElementById('wfqbeResults');

    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $divElement->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
    $innerHTML = $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($innerHTML);
    //$divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagname('td');

        /*** the array to return ***/
        $out = array();
        foreach ($divElementNew as $item)
        {
            /*** add node value to the out array ***/
            $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
        }

    echo '<pre>';

print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';

}?>
```

Where to put the following lines

```
multicall('60089');
multicall('60152');
multicall('60242');
/*...*/
```

This is still repetitive, so we can put the numbers in an array - can ´t we! 
Then we can loop through the array.

```
$numbers = array ('60089', '60152', '60242' /*...*/);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    doStuff($number);
}
```

But the question is - how to and where to put the loop!?

Can anybody give me a starting point...

BTW - if i have to be more descriptive i am trying to explain more - just let me know... 
it is no problem to explain more

greetings
Zero

**UPDATE: thaks to the great help i now have made a big step**

```
<?php

    function multiload ($uid) {
    /*...*/
    //  $uid = '60119';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

             $dom->loadHTMLFile('basic-url ' . $uid);


         }

    multiload ('60089');
    multiload ('60152');
    multiload ('60242');
    /*...*/

    $divElement = $dom->getElementById('wfqbeResults');

    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $divElement->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
    $innerHTML = $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($innerHTML);
    //$divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $divElementNew = $dom->getElementsByTagname('td');

        /*** the array to return ***/
        $out = array();
        foreach ($divElementNew as $item)
        {
            /*** add node value to the out array ***/
            $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
        }

    echo '<pre>';

print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';

}

$numbers = array ('60089', '60152', '60242' /*...*/);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    multiload($number);
}

?>
```

i add the code a the end.... Now i have learned alot. By the way: I am very happy to be here!!!
Greetings zero
Now i try it out...

Comment: I wish more beginners posted thorough questions like this, showing what they've tried and being explicit about what they need help with.

Comment: hello marcog - i will do this. I have had several complaints about this. I did not know how to treat this .-... Later today i will read your "links" and do all what is needed - mans many thanks! you are great!! - zero!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function from outside the function definition. For example, you could place it directly after the closing `}` of the function:

```
<?php

function multiload ($uid) {
    // function code
}

$numbers = array ('60089', '60152', '60242' /*...*/);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    multiload($number);
}

?>
```

Calling the function from within itself is valid, but is definitely not what you desire. Read up on [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) if you're interested in finding out what happens when you call a function from within itself. It can be a very useful technique, but not here. But before reading up on recursion, I suggest you read some tutorials on writing functions such as [this one](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_functions_4.htm).

Comment: hello Marcog, many many thanks! 

This means, i should take care that the function (the "operation") encompasses everything from the line where $dom is initialized to the line with the right curly bracket after "</pre>" is echoed.
Again thanks - i try this out!!! Greetings zero